# Charging the lithium battery with higher rated charger

Tags: battery-charging, lithium-ion

This question is two fold:

1. What happens if lithium cells are connected to a higher current capacity charger? Say, a 10Ah 1C rated cell is charged with a charger of 20A. Would the battery only take the amount it requires and leave the rest alone?
2. What happens when the lithium cells are in a pack? Say a 48V (13s8p) is connected to a charger of 20A? Would the load be shared by 8 parallel cell joints?

Comment: 1. Same thing that happens to you when you try to drink from a firehose. Very bad. 2. Same thing when a bunch of people drink from the same firehose. Not so bad if you have enough people.

Comment: But if we have an adapter to the firehose that controlls/streamlines the pressure, there shouldn't be any problem. For instance there is a BMS in every battery pack.

Comment: You can try pitting your tiny BMS against the charger if you want, but all that extra energy that the BMS isn't letting into the battery has to go somewhere. Unlike a firehose, a charger is smart and will go out of its way to try and maintain 20A output.

Comment: Why would you use 2C in a 1C pack or cell?

Comment: I have 2 battery pack one made up of 18650 cells for which I don't know the max charge rate. The second one is made up of EV cells whereby each cell is 20Ah with a recommended charge rate of 0.5C/1C max. So, I wonder if I use one 20A charger for both packs.

Comment: For the 18650 pack, what is the configuration? Is it 13s8p like you said? Do you know what kind of cells are in it? So you know what type of BMS? If so, maybe put that in the question.

Comment: @mkeith It is a Chinese battery pack rated at 48V 25Ah. So I suspect it is 13S8P. I can't torn it apart but I think it must be some common cells like liitokala 3000mAh. The EV cells I know and have the datasheet.

Comment: Well, if it is 25 Ah, then it is probably OK to charge it at 20A. Obviously I can't promise anything since I have never seen the pack.

Answer (score 1):

> What happens if lithium cells are connected to a higher current capacity charger? Say, a 10Ah 1C rated cell is charged with a charger of 20A. Would the battery only take the amount it requires and leave the rest alone?

Nothing good happens. The cell will be charged at 20A until the voltage climbs high enough to initiate the CV portion of the charge cycle. Short cell life can be expected. Cell temperature will likely be pretty high, also. And cell death cannot be ruled out.

> What happens when the lithium cells are in a pack? Say a 48V (13s8p) is connected to a charger of 20A? Would the load be shared by 8 parallel cell joints?

Yes. The current will be shared. Not necessarily perfectly equally, but assuming the cells are all the same type and age, it should be fairly equal. Do not assemble high discharge rate packs from multiple cells unless they are exactly the same, from the same order and batch.

Comment: Isn't counter intuitive? Usually when a load is attached to a supply source of higher capacity, only the amount of current the load can take flows through the circuit. Why in case of battery, more current flows through the circuit even when there is less demand?

Comment: @azad.parinda Because the charger is made to be more of a current source than a voltage source.

Comment: When a load is attached to a VOLTAGE SOURCE the load takes only the amps it needs. When a battery (which is similar to a voltage source that can sink or source current) is connected to a charger operating in CC mode (CC = constant current) well, that is a different situation. During the CC portion of recharge, the charger outputs a constant current until the voltage per cell is around 4.2V and then it transitions to constant voltage (CV) operation.

Comment: So then how does the charger maintains the constant current? Usually, when a load is attached to the regulated switching supply, the current is maintained by sensing teh voltage and increasing accordingly when they drop due to current requirement of the load. But in case of CC, if load can't draw enough current, how could a regulated supply adjust voltage for higher current?

Comment: During the CC portion of charging, the charger senses current and maintains it constant. If the current is too low it responds by increasing the voltage until the current is at the target level. It will not increase the voltage higher than approximately 4.2 V per cell, though.